# How to get the second value of this xpath?

Tags: html, xpath

Below is the html.

```
<div class="list-items tab-pane fade active show" ng-class="type=='pay'?'show active':''" tabindex="1" id="pay-bills">

    <div ng-repeat="item in BillList.Result.categorizedBillNickBene" class="ng-scope">
        <h2 class="head ng-binding" ng-show="filtered.length!=0">Electricity Bill Payment</h2>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="item in BillList.Result.categorizedBillNickBene" class="ng-scope">
        <h2 class="head ng-binding" ng-show="filtered.length!=0">Gas Bill Payment</h2>
    </div>

</div>
```

I want to get the second h2 value i.e. "Gas Bill Payment". I wrote xpath as

```
//div[@id='pay-bills']//div//h2[@class='head ng-binding'][2]
```

The issue is I am unable to get the second value with "[2]". although when i insert "[1]" i get two values.

Answer (score 2):

Why this doesn't work :

```
//div[@id='pay-bills']//div//h2[@class='head ng-binding'][2]
```

You're looking for an `h2` element whith a position equals to 2. All `h2` elements in your sample data are in first (1) position.

You can use the solution proposed by @chrisis or could go with :

```
(//div[@id='pay-bills']/div/h2)[2]/text()
```

Use `()` to specify you want the second displayed result of the XPath enclosed by `()`.

Be sure also to remove the unnecessary `//` from your expression (should be `/` since the second `div` and `h2` are child elements).

Answer (score 0):

Hope it may help.

```
>>> html = """ <div class="list-items tab-pane fade active show" ng-class="type=='pay'?'show active':''" tabindex="1" id="pay-bills"
... > 
...  
...     <div ng-repeat="item in BillList.Result.categorizedBillNickBene" class="ng-scope"> 
...         <h2 class="head ng-binding" ng-show="filtered.length!=0">Electricity Bill Payment</h2> 
...     </div> 
...  
...     <div ng-repeat="item in BillList.Result.categorizedBillNickBene" class="ng-scope"> 
...         <h2 class="head ng-binding" ng-show="filtered.length!=0">Gas Bill Payment</h2> 
...     </div> 
...  
... </div>"""                                                                                                                       

>>> html                                                                                                                            
' <div class="list-items tab-pane fade active show" ng-class="type==\'pay\'?\'show active\':\'\'" tabindex="1" id="pay-bills">\n\n    <div ng-repeat="item in BillList.Result.categorizedBillNickBene" class="ng-scope">\n        <h2 class="head ng-binding" ng-show="filtered.length!=0">Electricity Bill Payment</h2>\n    </div>\n\n    <div ng-repeat="item in BillList.Result.categorizedBillNickBene" class="ng-scope">\n        <h2 class="head ng-binding" ng-show="filtered.length!=0">Gas Bill Payment</h2>\n    </div>\n\n</div>'


>>> from pprint import pprint                                                                                                       

>>> pprint(html)                                                                                                                    
(' <div class="list-items tab-pane fade active show" '
 'ng-class="type==\'pay\'?\'show active\':\'\'" tabindex="1" id="pay-bills">\n'
 '\n'
 '    <div ng-repeat="item in BillList.Result.categorizedBillNickBene" '
 'class="ng-scope">\n'
 '        <h2 class="head ng-binding" ng-show="filtered.length!=0">Electricity '
 'Bill Payment</h2>\n'
 '    </div>\n'
 '\n'
 '    <div ng-repeat="item in BillList.Result.categorizedBillNickBene" '
 'class="ng-scope">\n'
 '        <h2 class="head ng-binding" ng-show="filtered.length!=0">Gas Bill '
 'Payment</h2>\n'
 '    </div>\n'
 '\n'
 '</div>')

>>> from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse                                                                                            

>>> response = HtmlResponse(url='my html string', body=html, encoding='utf-8')                                                      

>>> response.xpath('//div')                                                                                                         
[<Selector xpath='//div' data='<div class="list-items tab-pane fade ...'>, <Selector xpath='//div' data='<div ng-repeat="item in BillList.Resu...'>, <Selector xpath='//div' data='<div ng-repeat="item in BillList.Resu...'>]


>>> response.xpath('//div').getall()                                                                                                
['<div class="list-items tab-pane fade active show" ng-class="type==\'pay\'?\'show active\':\'\'" tabindex="1" id="pay-bills">\n\n    <div ng-repeat="item in BillList.Result.categorizedBillNickBene" class="ng-scope">\n        <h2 class="head ng-binding" ng-show="filtered.length!=0">Electricity Bill Payment</h2>\n    </div>\n\n    <div ng-repeat="item in BillList.Result.categorizedBillNickBene" class="ng-scope">\n        <h2 class="head ng-binding" ng-show="filtered.length!=0">Gas Bill Payment</h2>\n    </div>\n\n</div>', '<div ng-repeat="item in BillList.Result.categorizedBillNickBene" class="ng-scope">\n        <h2 class="head ng-binding" ng-show="filtered.length!=0">Electricity Bill Payment</h2>\n    </div>', '<div ng-repeat="item in BillList.Result.categorizedBillNickBene" class="ng-scope">\n        <h2 class="head ng-binding" ng-show="filtered.length!=0">Gas Bill Payment</h2>\n    </div>']


>>> response.xpath('//div//h2').getall()                                                                                            
['<h2 class="head ng-binding" ng-show="filtered.length!=0">Electricity Bill Payment</h2>', '<h2 class="head ng-binding" ng-show="filtered.length!=0">Gas Bill Payment</h2>']


>>> response.xpath('//div//h2').getall()[1]                                                                                         
'<h2 class="head ng-binding" ng-show="filtered.length!=0">Gas Bill Payment</h2>'


>>> response.xpath('//div//h2/text()').getall()[1]                                                                                  
'Gas Bill Payment'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the second div, what you've tried would give you the second h2 inside the div if there was one.
Try

```
//div[@id='pay-bills']//div[2]//h2[@class='head ng-binding']
```